# why eclipse does not compile google examples?

Tags: android, eclipse, compiler-errors

I opened my last android project today and suddenly when I wanted to run it, eclipse returnd with the error “your project contains error(s). please fix them before running again” but before yesterday it did not have any errors and the red cross does not appear in the package explorer before running it today. Even now, **the red cross is just under the project directory and it is not present in any sub directories!** (what does it mean? normaly the chain goes to the root of the problam)

I tried google examples, and even the blank project and they all returned the same error with red cross for the root directory of the project and no red cross in any other file or directory! I don’t know what is wrong! Where should I look for the source of the errors?

I am using:

Eclipse  juno version 4.2.0 (last version)

ADT 20.0.2 (last version)

SDK  4.0.3

Windows 7

I re installed the eclipse and ADT but still even the examples cannot run! What is probably wrong?

Comment: Have you tried cleaning?

Comment: what does the "Problems" or "Marker" in eclipse tell you about the error?

Comment: Look at the "problems" pannel. Sometimes it does not show any problems because the problems are in librarys etc.

Comment: I didn’t know that “problems” panel exists! Finally I found the underlying error but still it does not make sense, because I don’t understand the error: Debug Certificate expired on 7/31/12 1:53 AM

Comment: That error is pretty self explanatory...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The debug certificate is only valid for a year.  You need to delete it (Eclipse will generate another).

On a mac, delete the file ~/.android/debug.keystore.

In windows, delete the file c:\users\yourname\android\debug.keystore.

Comment: It wasted my entire day! Why would they do that?